# Is android sqlite database synchronized with read and write operation?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-database

I have a singleton `SQLiteOpenHelper` object which I will be using all over the application. I tried performing `read` and `write` tasks in parallel from different threads with singleton database helper object but I didn't see any `DataBaseLockException` or `DataBaseBusyException`.

Does android perform any in-built locking mechanism for all database operations?

Comment: https://www.sqlite.org/threadsafe.html

Comment: @juergend it states The default mode is serialized. is it in android?